# Make sure that the overriding service 'wins'

Tags: services

#### Setup

I have multiple sites that are very similar and therefore share the same code base. I have a custom module **common** with functionality common to all sites. Then for each site I have a specific module **site_a**, **site_b** etc where site specific code resides.

I want to create custom services such that **common** has a default implementation that **site_a** can override if necessary.

#### Specific use case

On user creation, for example, the different sites need to run mostly the same routines, but not entirely. In this case I would place each specific routine as methods in `Drupal\common\Service\UserCreationService.php` and call them one at a time from `hook_user_insert()`:

```
$user_creation_service = \Drupal::service('my_module.user_creation_service');
$user_insert_service->routine_1();
$user_insert_service->routine_2();
// etc
```

If site A needs a different routine I would let `Drupal\site_a\Service\UserCreationService.php` extend `Drupal\common\Service\UserCreationService.php` and replace the relevant method. Of course this functionality could easily be achieved by simply reimplementing the same hook in **site_a**, but I find the service method much clearer and with less boilerplate.

#### Minimal example

There are two ways to override services as far as I can tell from [this documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic). One is to implement the `MyModuleServiceProvider::alter()`, another (for core services) is to specify (an override for) the service in `my_module.services.yml`. The second method seems to also work for custom services, which is was prompted this question.

Consider this example:

```yaml
# File: modules/common/common.services.yml
services:
  common.test_service:
    class: Drupal\common\Service\TestService
```

```php
// File: modules/common/src/Service/TestService.php
namespace Drupal\common\Service;

class TestService {
  public function sayMyName() {
    return 'common';
  }
}
```

```yml
# File: modules/site_a/site_a.services.yml
services:
  common.test_service:
    class: Drupal\site_a\Service\TestService
```

```php
// File: modules/site_a/src/Service/TestService.php
namespace Drupal\site_a\Service;

class TestService extends \Drupal\common\Service\TestService {
  public function sayMyName() {
    return 'site_a';
  }
}
```

Now `echo \Drupal::service('common.test_service')->sayMyName()` outputs 'common' when **site_a** is uninstalled and outputs 'site_a' when **site_a** is installed - exactly as wanted! But it seems a bit flaky, as the linked documentation says:

> If multiple modules swap the same service, then neither module can predict if their swapped service will win eventually.

This should not be a problem because I define a service in one module and override it in another (even though in this example I do it in the services.yml file). But I don't completely trust that this is just a lucky coincidence when the services share the same name.

I would much prefer if I could explicitly set the hierarchy and specify that the service i **site_a** overrides a service from **common**, but this does not seem to be possible.

#### Question

How can I be absolutely sure that it's the service from **site_a** that is fetched from the service container and not the one from **common**? Do I have to use `MyModuleServiceProvider::alter()` instead of the services.yml file, and even then can I make sure that everything works?

Bonus question: Is this best practice, or should I be doing something else?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called [Service Decoration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html). This is something you should look up in the Symfony documentation, it is not really Drupal specific.

Comment: The documentation is not entirely correct, it is predictable as long as you have control over the modules installed. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241279/serviceproviderbase-override-winner-can-this-be-done-with-module-weight

Comment: @4k4 that's brilliant, I had no idea Module Weight was a thing. That is more or less the hierarchy I need. For a simple task like this the complete override seems simpler/cleaner than the decorating pattern. But the module weight has to be controlled in a different part of the system - the decorating service can be specified directly in services.yml file and that does smell less. What would you recommend as best practice?

Comment: If you have services in multiple modules competing against each other having the highest priority the simplest way to implement would be tagged services and a `service_collector`. See core.services.yml for examples.